# Poppler compiling using QT4 under Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, qt4

How can I compile poppler 0.13.3 using Visual Studio 2008, and with QT4 support? I want to use poppler as a static lib.

Can anyone help, or has anyone done this?

Thanks

Comment: Plz, add some additional information to your question: do you have already working pair MSVC+Qt? Why do you doesn't use mingw? What was the problems, when you tried to build popper with MSVC+Qt?

Comment: hey mosg, yes I have msvc2k8+qt4 (opensource). I didn't found good information on how to build poppler for windows using vs2008.

After I download the poppler package from their website, I unpacked and cant see any way of how to configure it to create a vs2008 project... under mac, just type ./configure in terminal and is ready to go, but on Windows, I just don't know how...

Yes, I consider myself a newbie when dealing with makefiles...

So, if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great...

Thanks